# Advice with zooming on CCLayerPanZoom Cocos Extensions

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Hy,

I have started developing a RPG Game. I use a Isometric tyle map which I put on a CCLayerPanZoom.
Now I want to position spites on the tile map. As I click I get a deviated position for the place where the new Sprite is positioned on the Map.
Why? Is there a sliding between layers? Is there a way to attach the map to the zoom layer so the click position coresponds to the place on the map where I want to put the new sprite.

Please help.

Here is my init()
For the ones who want to see it just jave a look at the zip which contains the Xcode project. It is a Kobold2D project.
I have the same project but without the CCLayerPanZoom layer. There the positioning is working perfect. 
IMPORTANT REMARK: WHEN THE MAP IS DRAGGED SO THAT THE LEFT EDGE IS EXACTLY ON THE BORDER OF THE LEFT SIDE OF THE IPAD SIMULATOR THEN THE TILE PLACING IS ALMOST OK. TILES ARE PLACED AT APROXIMATIVELY THE RIGHT PLACE.

```
   - (id) init
   {
    if ((self = [super init])) 
    {
    //touches enables
    self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

    //instantiate the PanZoomLayer
    panZoomLayer = [CCLayerPanZoom node];
    //seting poperties for the pan zoom layer
    panZoomLayer.maxScale = 1.0f;
    panZoomLayer.minScale = 0.2f;
    panZoomLayer.maxSpeed = 100.0f;
    panZoomLayer.maxTouchDistanceToClick = 1000.0f;
    panZoomLayer.panBoundsRect = CGRectNull;
    panZoomLayer.mode = kCCLayerPanZoomModeSheet;


    //add the zoom layer to the CCLayer
    [self addChild: panZoomLayer z:-1];

    //if I uncoment this it thros me an error by ccTouchesEnded
    //It has to be commented like this
            //panZoomLayer.delegate = self; 

    self.map = [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"isometric-no-offset.tmx"];

    _map.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
            _map.scale = CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();

    layer = [_map layerNamed:@"Ground"];
    layer.visible = YES;

    [panZoomLayer addChild: _map 
                         z :-1 
                        tag:kTileMapTag];
            // create and initialize a Label
            CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString: @"Zooming and scroling Demo" 
                                           fontName: @"Marker Felt" 
                                           fontSize: 30];
            label.scale = 0.7f; //< to be visible on iPod Touch screen.
            label.color = ccBLUE;
            // add the label as a child to this Layer
            [panZoomLayer addChild: label 
                          z: 1 
                        tag:kLabelTag];

    _player = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ninja.png"];


    //map size 
    mapHeight = _map.contentSize.height;
    mapWidth = _map.contentSize.width;

    //screen size
    CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    screenCenter = CGPointMake(screenSize.width / 2, screenSize.height / 2);


    //Hide/Show character
    [_player setVisible:YES];
    _player.position = ccp(300, 400);
    [panZoomLayer addChild:_player z:2];

    //dot initialization
    self.dot = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"d2.png"];
    //_dot. position = ccp(200,200);
    [_map addChild:dot z:3];

    panZoomLayer.mode = kCCLayerPanZoomModeSheet;
    panZoomLayer.minScale = 0.6f;
    panZoomLayer.maxScale = 2.0f;
    panZoomLayer.rubberEffectRatio = 1.1f;



    //test different scren reshapes
    //the zooming and scroling works also without any of the following methods


    //simple. until now the most convenient
    [self updateForScreenReshape1];

    //ruber. means center on screen. zoom out more in as previous
    //[self updateForScreenReshape2];

    //with zones. zoom out more and in less
    //[self updateForScreenReshape3];

}

return self;
```

}
gBoy
Baby Hacker

Posts: 8
Joined: Thu May 10, 2012 7:26 pm
Has thanked: 0 time
Been thanked: 0 time

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that you touch/click the screen to place a sprite and the sprite shows up in some random seeming place, not where you wanted?

I haven't used Kobold2D (I use vanilla iOS cocos2D mostly) but it sounds like yes there is "a sliding between layers" going on. When you add _map as a child of panZoomLayer, _map will inherit any movement that occurs in panZoomLayer.

To get the sprites sitting on the _map layer correctly you have to calculate the difference in position from the panZoomLayer to the screen center and use that value to adjust the position of the sprite.

You could do something equivalent to this in your ccTouch method when you make a new sprite:

```
CGPoint location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:[touch locationInView:[touch view]]];

[newSprite setPosition: ccpSub(screenCenter, location)];
```

Btw, the positions would have seemed to work out ok when the map is dragged to the left because then the offset from it's origin is at (or near) 0.